# Unexpected alignment in menu using CSS3 + HTML5 when I add an input and a div

Tags: html, css

I'm new using html5 and css3. I'm trying to create a basic web for a final project.

Basically I need a menu on the left side (fixed position) + input button in the top - center position + div in which to display all content uploaded (text file).

Here is the fiddle of the full code: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h8pmk2kv/2/)

As you can see, the menu scrolls down.

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background-color:#bababa;
  color:#fff;
}

div#fileOutput{
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 960px;
  height: 800px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type="file"]{
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  white-space: pre-line;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;

}

#nav {
  border:3px solid #3e4547;
  box-shadow:2px 2px 8px #000000;
  border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;
}
#nav ul li {
  margin-top:-23px;
  -moz-transition:  0.4s linear 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
  background-color:#d4d5d8;
  color:#000;
  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height:28px;
  outline:0;
  padding-left:15px;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
  background:#d4d5d8 url("../images/down.gif") no-repeat;
}
#nav li a + img {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:none;
  height:28px;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:200px;
}
#nav li a img {
  border-width:0px;
  height:24px;
  line-height:28px;
  margin-right:8px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:24px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color:#bcbdc1;
}
#nav ul li a {
  background-color:#eee;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  color:#000;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color:#ddd;
  color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
  background: url("../images/bulb.png") no-repeat;
  border-width:0px;
  height:16px;
  line-height:22px;
  margin-right:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
  background:url("../images/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav a.sub:focus {
  background:#bcbdc1;
  outline:0;
}
#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
  margin-top:0;

  -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
  -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
}
#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
  display:block;
}
#nav a.sub:active {
  background:#bcbdc1;
  outline:0;
}
#nav a:active ~ ul li {
  margin-top:0;
}
#nav ul:hover li {
  margin-top:0;
}
```

Expected result:

[image: concept]
Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Comment: All you have to do is add `position: fixed; top: 0;` to `#nav`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS change:

```
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    background-color:#bababa;
    color:#fff;
}

div#fileOutput{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}

input[type="file"]{
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;

}

#nav {
    border:3px solid #3e4547;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 8px #000000;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav ul {
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin-top:-23px;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s linear 0.4s;
}
#nav li a {
    background-color:#d4d5d8;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:28px;
    outline:0;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li a.sub {
    background:#d4d5d8 url("../images/down.gif") no-repeat;
}
#nav li a + img {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:28px;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
}
#nav li a img {
    border-width:0px;
    height:24px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin-right:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:24px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#bcbdc1;
}
#nav ul li a {
    background-color:#eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    color:#000;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:22px;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#ddd;
    color:#444;
}
#nav ul li a img {
    background: url("../images/bulb.png") no-repeat;
    border-width:0px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin-right:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
}
#nav ul li:nth-child(odd) a img {
    background:url("../images/bulb2.png") no-repeat;
}
#nav a.sub:focus {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:focus ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;

    -moz-transition:  0.4s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.4s linears;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s linears;
    transition: 0.4s linear;
}
#nav a:focus + img, #nav a:active + img {
    display:block;
}
#nav a.sub:active {
    background:#bcbdc1;
    outline:0;
}
#nav a:active ~ ul li {
    margin-top:0;
}
#nav ul:hover li {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<input id="fileInput" placeholder=":input" type="file" size="50" onchange="processFiles(this.files)">
<div id="fileOutput"></div>
<!--<div id="parseOutput" style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>-->
 <div class="container">

            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/t1.png" /> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/t2.png" />HTML/CSS</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sub" tabindex="1"><img src="images/t3.png" />jQuery/JS</a><img src="images/up.gif" alt="" />
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 8</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 9</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/empty.gif" />Link 10</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/t2.png" />PHP</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/t2.png" />MySQL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images/t2.png" />XSLT</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
</body>
```